# SQL Server 2008 - Remove characters from multiple rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the below sample data and I would like to remove the word "Division" from the data set.

Table A:

```
Central Division
North Division
East Division
```

Comment: Is this not just a simple REPLACE statement? Would you expect the first row to be deleted entirely, or just turned into empty string? What about the space character preceeding `Division` in the other three examples, would that be kept or removed?

Comment: So thats 3 rows?  Is the word you want to remove always the last one? Is its length known?

Comment: I have updated my question to remove "Division" as a value. That is the table name. Yes, I would also like the space character to be removed too.

Comment: Yes, Division is the last word on every value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may looking for simple update statement

```
Update T
Set ColumnName=RTRIM(REPLACE(ColumnName,'Division','')) 
FROM TableName t
WHERE   ColumnName like '%Division%'
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this:**

```
Update A
```

`Set ColumnName=Ltrim(REPLACE(ColumnName,'Division',''))
FROM TableName A
WHERE   ColumnName like '%Division%'`

**Or for null :**

```
Update A
Set Column = Null
Where Column Like '%Division%'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Division is the last word on every value

As the word is always at the end and of a fixed length the best way is to simply chop off the last 9 characters:

```
update t set fld = left(fld, len(fld) - 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

That do all of the job for you- Removing all ' Division' from sample table.

```
  DECLARE @Table Table
(
    nameOfColumn VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
('Central Division'),
('North Division'),
('East Division')


UPDATE @Table
SET nameOfColumn = REPLACE(nameOfColumn,' Division','')
FROM @Table

SELECT * FROM @Table
```